# Stop /index.php?ACT=8&id=G3UISGtdz attacks

Tags: spam

Our server is being hit with spam requests related to new membership via a url query. The query looks like /index.php?ACT=8&id=G3UISGtdz, with the id changing. This is an older EE 1.6.8 site. I have disabled new membership, but the request keep coming.

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Contact your server hosting company and ask to ban the ip that keeps making these requests. If you are in control of the server, then blacklist the ip. If there are multiple ip addresses then you have a much more serious problem.

Comment: Thanks. I do have control server, but it is multiple ip addresses. Is there somewhere in the code I can stop ACT=8 from firing? Eventually however I need to allow new memberships.

Comment: Maybe for now you should look into just blocking that type of request with the .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question on StackOverflow: [How to block bot requests to URLs that match a common pattern in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640807/how-to-block-bot-requests-to-urls-that-match-a-common-pattern-in-apache)

Drop this in your .htaccess file.  It will match any variation of the querystring that you seem to be getting spammed on. With this mod_rewrite rule, if a querystring tries to fire `ACT=8`, the Apache will simply respond with a 403 Forbidden.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(ACT=8).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```